# What is the relationship of #line to global static scope?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

Given a C file (foo.c) as follows:

```
#line 1 "a.c"
static int bar = 1;
#line 2 "b.c"
static int bar = 2;
#line 2 "a.c"
int foo(){
    return bar;
}
```

Are the two declarations of bar in the same scope or separate scopes (i.e. would foo() return 1)?

Note: I am interested in the correct behavior based on the standard, not just "what does my compiler do" (hence the language-lawyer tag)

Comment: `#line` is a preprocessor directive, it has nothing to do with variable scopes.

Comment: The only thing `#line` is used for is displaying the original source line number in diagnostic messages. It has no effect at all on the semantics of the program.

Comment: As written the code will not compile either way.

Comment: #line changes "presumed name of the source file". That seems like it should affect "file scope".

Comment: @Barmar `#line` also modifies `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Scope is based on translation units, not filenames.

Comment: you will get a complaint if two variable has the same name by sane c compilers.

Comment: A translation unit is the combined file after all `#include` files are merged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#line` information doesn't change the translation unit (TU).  Your TU (the source file plus included files) contains two definitions of the same (`static`) variable.  This is an error.  The compiler rejects it.  How it reports the error may be affected by the `#line` directives, but the error will be reported regardless of the `#line` directives — the compiler is attempting to compile a single TU and the TU is faulty.